# Can webhooks return the response code as well as message from the api endpoint?

Tags: dynamics-crm, webhooks, microsoft-dynamics, power-automate, msdn

I have setup a `webhook` to trigger a power automate flow whenever a particular table/data is updated at `MSD (microsoft dataverse)`. Within the power automate flow, if a validation fails am responding with `400 status code` to the `webhook` which in turn throw this error in `MSD` -

```
Endpoint unavailable
Microsoft Dynamics 365 can’t complete your request. 
The webhook service endpoint may be configured incorrectly or is not available. 
Contact the service endpoint owner or your system administrator 
to validate your configuration. If the problem persists, 
contact Microsoft Dynamics 365 customer support for help.
```

Is it possible to pass additional messages back to `MSD` when validations fail in flow, explaining what exactly failed, so that users a `MSD` can take appropriate actions?

Or is there any other way to validate operations(CRUD) done at `MSDN/Dynamics365`? (I am new to `Microsoft dataverse`)